# When a destructor is called and what is used for in this example?

Tags: c++, destructor

Can anyone tells me what the destructor does in this code? a call example:
"

```
int year = 2012; 
string hello = "Hello"; 
cout << format("% world! The year is %\n") << hello << year;
```

"
I dont get the idea of a destructor with "while" . . . why do we need it? this should print: "Hello world! The year is 2012" . . . if I understand well, so the destructor is called when a "throw" is called that means in the end of the str ?

```
TempFormat format(const char*) { 
  return TempFormat(const char*); 
} 

class TempFormat { 
  const char* str; 
public: 
  TempFormat(const char* str) : str(str) {} 

  friend Format& operator<<(ostream& os, TempFormat& f) { 
    return Format(f.str, os); 
  } 
};

class Format {
  const char* str; 
  ostream& os; 
public: 
  Format(const char* str, ostream& os) : str(str), os(os) {} 

  template<class T> 
  Format& operator<<(const T& t) { 
    while(*str && *str != '%'){ 
      os << *str; 
      str++; 
    } 
    if (*str != '%') { 
      throw std::exception(); 
    } 
    os << t; 
    while(*str && *str != '%'){ 
      os << *str; 
      str++; 
    } 
    return *this; 
  } 

  ~Format() { 
    while(*str && *str != '%'){ 
      os << *str; 
      str++; 
    } 
    if (*str == '%') { 
      throw std::exception(); 
    } 
  } 
};
```

Comment: Destructors are what power RAII. Also, throwing an exception in a destructor is a huge no, and I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish in the first place.

Comment: I don't understand your question or why this non-indented code is related to it.

Comment: why do we have this:"
while(*str && *str != '%'){ 
 os << *str; 
 str++; 
 } 
 if (*str == '%') { 
 throw std::exception();
"
in the constructor? what it does ?

Comment: I think in the destructor, an exception is thrown if there is still a, unprocessed '%' in the format string. **Edit:** And in the `operator<<` override, an exception is thrown if the operator is called while there is no '%' left in the format string.

Comment: but what the destructor`s purpose ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The destructor merely checks that all the '%' in the format strings have been processed. If the string contains more '%' than the object received arguments, the destructor throws an exception.

**Edit:** The line `cout << format("% world! The year is %\n") << hello << year;` is very devious because none of the `<<` operators here are classical `ostream& operator<<(ostream&, type)` overloads.

- The first `<<` is actually `Format& operator<<(ostream&, TempFormat&)`, which returns a Format object. It's also an abomination that returns a local variable by reference, and takes a nameless temporary variable by non-constant reference. Does it even compile? Its prototype should probably be `Format operator<<(ostream&, TempFormat const&)` instead. But without Return Value Optimization (or a good *move constructor*), it would throw.
- The second '<<' is actually `Format`'s insertion operator `Format& Format::operator<<(const T&)`, with the `string` type.
- The third '<<' is actually `Format`'s insertion operator `Format& Format::operator<<(const T&)`, with the `int` type.

Since the `Format` object is a temporary, it's destroyed at the end of the line, after its `operator<<` has been called twice. And since it contained exactly two '%', its destructor doesn't throw.